# Form submitting even after Validation fail

Tags: javascript

My form is submitting even after the validation fails and alert appears for some specific field for correction.

```
function validateForm() {
    var subscriberName = trimAll(document.getElementById("subscriberName").value);

    //Validators like this
    if (subscriberName.length < 1) { alert("Please enter First Name.");
        document.getElementById("subscriberName").focus(); return false; } else { var iChars="_!@#$%^&*()+=-[]\\\';,./{}|\"
        :<>?1234567890";
        var flag = "false";
        for (var i = 0; i < subscriberName.length; i++) { if (iChars.indexOf(subscriberName.charAt(i)) !=-1) {
            alert("The First name has special character or numbers. \nThis is not allowed.");
            document.getElementById("subscriberName").focus(); return false; } }
            document.getElementById("subscriberForm").submit(); }
```

Comment: Provide HTML too

Comment: Hope you are doing e.preventDefault(); to stop the default action of the submit event of the form.

Comment: <button name="button" class="button" id="button" onclick="javascript: validateForm();" value="Update">
          <span style="color:#FFFFFF; font-size: 15px">Add </span>
         </button>

Comment: <form name="subscriberForm" modelAttribute="subscriberRequest" method="post" action="/subscriber/saveAjaxSubscriber.htm"
 id="subscriberForm">

Comment: this is my HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your button's `onclick`. Add `return` in it as `onclick="javascript: return validateForm();"`.

Your button's html should be as below.

```
<button name="button" class="button" id="button" onclick="javascript: return validateForm();" value="Update"> <span style="color:#FFFFFF; font-size: 15px">Add </span> </button>
```

You can test it below.

```js
function validateForm() { 
  return false;
}
function validateFormTrue() { 
  return true;
}
```

```html
<form name="subscriberForm" modelAttribute="subscriberRequest" method="post" action="/subscriber/saveAjaxSubscriber.htm" id="subscriberForm">
  <button name="button" class="button" id="button" onclick="javascript: return validateForm();" value="Update"> <span style="color:#FFFFFF; font-size: 15px">return false test </span> </button>      
  <button name="button" class="button" id="button" onclick="javascript: return validateFormTrue();" value="Update"> <span style="color:#FFFFFF; font-size: 15px">return true test </span> </button>
</form>
```